# Setting up ALB configuration for Keycloak OIDC

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, aws-application-load-balancer

Is there a way to get Keycloak to work as an OIDC Provider for AWS ALBs?

I am trying to use an AWS ALB associated with Keycloak Authorization Services to be able to perform authorization for my resources.

I have managed to configure the ALB to have Keycloak OIDC perform the authentication but I would like also Keycloak to perform an authorization check.

I created a new confidential client and provided to ALB with the **clientID** and **secret** as well as the OIDC Urls [like., **issuer_url**, **authorization_url**, **token_url**, **userinfo_url**].

After setting up the ALB with the keycloak authorization server. I am able to get the keycloak login page when I hit the public DNS of an ALB. But after entering the valid credentials and submit the login form, It is throwing the 500 internal server error.

I have tried and tried and I am just getting stuck with 500 Internal Server.

This is the request that gets the 500 error:

```
https://<public DNS of my ALB>/oauth2/idpresponse?state=PWISnbHmRCVpxmqyn%2FrKsHdJzbKFnfz5GxhnlCyVdnxRVV%2F9kvj7O0JCjQOuf1DNL08h821PorJGGa3%2F4fzFymulG8sS%2FxhLFQS5gNrpuQyCf9DCzrwFxkIbG3I2sHywK7%2FeDmfYUH6Rej%2FEJ4RQwdjpjm76Z1wycw%2FGjQIRxehaTqNtCS%2FdXhm2oag%2FBnY%2FkuMiB8Q%3D&session_state=3a94a1d6-5e75-491b-a231-e4a1a469e5cb&code=23364bac-92e9-4094-9dc3-19c15eb42e7c.3a94a1d6-5e75-491b-a231-e4a1a469e5cb.9723ee49-5bca-4ff6-8a13-f7539b0bc28c
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear how did you setup authorization (not authentication).

Comment: I followed the link https://developers.onelogin.com/blog/aws-alb-openid-connect to set up keycloak authorization server at AWS ALB.

Comment: That's only about authentication, not authorization. Authentication != Authorization. Contact your AWS support, they can see more ALB logs. It looks like your ALB can't exchange for some reason code for a token.

Comment: Thanks, @JanGaraj. I got the response my AWS support as below: 
1. 500 was a result of using Self sigined certificate on ALB which is not supported for Authentication
2. Use real certifcate  on ALB not not self sigined one